# Rasterio and OpenCV shows two different pixel arrays for same image

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, opencv

I am using Rasterio to open a panchromatic GeoTiff image file.
The syntax I used to open the GeoTIFF file using Rasterio:

```
import rasterio

src = rasterio.open('Birmingham_Shuttleworth_s106_20200409T191236Z_Basic_Panchromatic/20200409_191236_ssc6d3_0015_basic_panchromatic.tif')
band_1 = src.read(1)
```

The array I can see after doing

```
In [23]: band_1
Out[23]: 
array([[3466, 3865, 3929, ..., 4472, 4520, 4456],
       [3546, 3657, 3721, ..., 4568, 4728, 4504],
       [3562, 3689, 3945, ..., 4696, 4504, 4568],
       ...,
       [5606, 5622, 5478, ..., 4376, 4264, 4424],
       [5558, 5526, 5462, ..., 4600, 4504, 4536],
       [5558, 5510, 5462, ..., 4824, 4696, 5175]], dtype=uint16)
```

However, when I open the same GeoTIFF file using OpenCV:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('Birmingham_Shuttleworth_s106_20200409T191236Z_Basic_Panchromatic/20200409_191236_ssc6d3_0015_basic_panchromatic.tif',0)
```

I can see:

```
In [44]: img
Out[44]: 
array([[13, 15, 15, ..., 17, 17, 17],
       [13, 14, 14, ...,  0,  0,  0],
       [13, 14, 15, ...,  0,  0,  0],
       ...,
       [21, 21, 21, ..., 13,  9, 11],
       [21, 21, 21, ...,  0,  0,  0],
       [21, 21, 21, ...,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=uint8)
```

I see that the pixel type(?) is `uint8` in OpenCV and `uint16` in Rasterio. Below are some of the questions that I have.

1. What and why is this happening?
2. What are those numbers that I see in the arrays? Are they pixel values? If yes, why are they not from 0-255? Do panchromatic image pixels have a different range?

I have just started image processing using Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could reproduce these results with Landsat-8 panchromatic band.

When you are using `cv2.imread(fl,0)` it reads image as greyscale 8 bit (0-255), you should either read it as `cv2.imread(fl,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)` or `cv2.imread(fl,-1)` since your original image has 16 bit depth (0-65535)

as for the other question

> What are those numbers that I see in the arrays? Are they pixel values? If yes, why are they not from 0-255? Do panchromatic image pixels have a different range?

The numbers are resulted from `OpenCV` simple depth scaling and is estimated as following: `(pixel_value/65535)*255` with `65535` being the maximum possible value of 16 bit image and 255 maximum possible value of 8 bit image.

For example in your `rasterio` output pixel value at `(0,0)` is `3466`, `(3466/65535)*255=13.480827308501876` which is the same (with an exception of rounding) as your `OpenCV` output at `(0,0)`